# ComboBox is not updating when BindableCollection<T> is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, caliburn.micro

I'm building a WPF Application using Caliburn.Micro for MVVM. I'm trying to add a client while the application is running but can't get the ComboBox to update/refresh. By printing to the console, I have confirmed that the BindableCollection has an item being added to it, but even though I've included the line:

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Clients);
```

in the Property definition, the ComboBox isn't being updated/refreshed.

Heres the code:

The ComboBox control in ShellView.xaml

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="200" Margin="0,0,0,5"
          x:Name="Clients" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The button control in NewClientView.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="AddClient" Content="Add Client" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
```

The Property in ShellViewModel.cs:

```
public BindableCollection<ClientModel> Clients
{
    get
    {
        return _clients;
    }
    set
    {
        _clients = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Clients);
    }
}
```

The back-code for the button in NewClientViewModel.cs (a user control for adding a new client):

```
public void AddClient(BindableCollection<ClientModel> Clients)
{
    DataAccess.Clients.Add(new ClientModel
    {
        ClientName = ClientNameInput,
        ClientProducts = null
    });

    Clients = new BindableCollection<ClientModel>(DataAccess.Clients);

    TryClose(true);
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

### *Edit 1

When I try to add the client directly with this code:

```
public void AddClient(BindableCollection<ClientModel> Clients)
{
    Clients.Add(new ClientModel
    {
        ClientName = ClientNameInput,
        ClientProducts = null
    });

    TryClose(true);
}
```

it throws a 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' - Inner Exception 1: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

### *Edit 2

The constructor for my ShellViewModel:

```
public ShellViewModel()
{
    Clients = new BindableCollection<ClientModel>(GenerateTestData());
}
```

GenerateTestData() returns a List of type ClientModel.

The call to open the UserControl to add a new client:

```
public void LoadNewClient()
{
    ActivateItem(new NewClientViewModel());
}
```

Comment: There is nothing like `ItemSource="{Binding Clients}"`, so how is `Clients = new ...` supposed to update anything? Note that using a BindableCollection is pointless when you only ever create new collection instances, but never add or remove items to/from an existing instance.

Comment: You may perhaps just drop `DataAccess.Clients` and just call `Clients.Add(...)`. Then the Clients property may also be declared readonly.

Comment: I posted the code I originally tried but was getting an error. I will try to add as read-only.

Comment: `Clients` has of course to be initialized. Declare it like `public BindableCollection<ClientModel> Clients { get; } = new BindableCollection<ClientModel>();`

Comment: I initialized it in the constructor of my ShellViewModel. I don't think I'm passing it into the NewClientViewModel(UserControl/Screen) so I'm assuming that's why it's not being updated. What's the best way to pass variables between ViewModels?

Answer (score 0):

Use the EventAggregator to pass variables between ViewModels. I can explain in more detail if the [standard documentation](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator) isn't enough.